# Undefined control sequence Title page

Tags: author

In the following code I'm trying to design the into page of my thesis. unfortunately, my name is not defined

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{masterthesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{dirtytalk} 
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}} 
\usepackage{placeins} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\graphicspath{{images/}} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        \Huge
        \textbf{Thesis Title }

        \vspace{1.5cm}

        \author{author name }

        \advisor{Prof.Name 1 \\
                prof. Name 2 }

        \examiner{Prof. Name 3}

        \vfill

        A thesis presented for the degree of\\
        Master of Data Science and Engineering

        \vspace{0.8cm}

        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/university.jpg}
         \vspace{0.8cm}

        \large
        Department of Informatics, Gioengineering, Robotics, and Systems Engineering\\
        University of Genoa\\
        Italy-Genoa\\
        2019\\

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

but the output is with error of undefined control sequence and the name of author cannot appear

Comment: Please create a complete minimal working example (MWE) of your current code including the document class and needed packages as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For me I made a file for each part of thesis, so there is file for title which invoked in the main file

Comment: here is where I invoke the title page 
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{masterthesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\graphicspath{{images/}}


\begin{document}

\input{titlepage.tex}

Comment: @Peter Where did you get the class file "masterthesis.cls" ?

Comment: no one can run your example as posted, to see the issue and you have not shown the error message so it is hard to help. Please show the exact error message from the log file from `1` to `?` in a code block so line endings are preserved, that would show which command was undefined.